# Solving $e^{-t \epsilon } \text{csch}(t) \sinh (t-t \epsilon )=\epsilon$ for small $\epsilon$

Tags: equation-solving, numerics

I'm trying to solve the following equation for small values of $\epsilon$, ie, $\epsilon\approx 10^{-12}$.

$$e^{-t \epsilon } \text{csch}(t) \sinh (t-t \epsilon ) = \epsilon$$

Using `FindRoot` below suffers from numerical precision issues, which don't appear to be addressed by extended precision. IE, using 100 digits of precision works for $\epsilon= 10^{-6}$, but gets stuck for $\epsilon=10^{-9}$

```
loss = E^(-ε t) Csch[t] Sinh[t - ε t];

prec = 100; setPrec[t_] := SetPrecision[t, prec + 1];
findSteps[e0_] := 
  Block[{ε = setPrec[e0]}, 
   t /. FindRoot[loss == ε, {t, 1/ε}, 
     WorkingPrecision -> prec]];

findSteps[10^-6]
```

Any tips?

[Notebook](https://www.wolframcloud.com/obj/yaroslavvb/nn-linear/forum-cosh-integral.nb)

Comment: Isn't it art for art's sake?

Comment: @user64494 the motivation is that it gives an upper bound on the number of gradient descent steps until loss is numerically 0, for an arbitrary quadratic objective, in limited precision determined by $\epsilon$

Comment: Sorry, don't understand you. Please, state your  motivation clearly.

Comment: The problem is equivalent to finding $t$ such that almost all of integral mass $\int_0^1 \exp(-2 t x)\mathrm{d}x$, is contained in the interval $[0,\epsilon]$. This integral comes up in analysis of gradient descent

Comment: Still don't understand what for.

Comment: Gradient is a notion in several variables, isn't so? Of course, the derivative may be treated as the coordinate of a one-dimensional gradient, but this is not usual.

Comment: @user64494 error $E[\|\mathbf{x}\|^2]$ after $t$ steps of gradient descent minimizing $\sum_i h_i x_i^2$ with isotropically random initial $\mathbf{x}$ is $\sum_i (1-h_i)^{2t}$. Approximate $(1-h_i)$ with $\exp(-h i)$ and write error as expectation over empirical density of $h_i$, $E[\exp(-2 t h)]$. Now you can ask how large must $t$ be until $E[\exp(-2 t h)]$ underflows to zero

Comment: Sorry,  I don't see any relation between the question  and $E[\exp(-2 t h)]$ where $h$ is a vector. Are you serious?

Comment: You can view $\frac{1}{n}\sum_i^n \exp(-2 t h_i)$ as expectation taken over empirical density of $h_i$, hence write $E[\exp(-2 t h)]$ as shorthand. Now approximate (discrete) empirical density of $h_i$'s with uniform (continuous) density, and you get the integral above. I think the reason for downvotes is people disagreeing with the tone, rather than the content

Comment: Sorry, this does not explain `ε`  in the LHS and RРS of `E^(-ε t) Csch[t] Sinh[t - ε t]==ε` simultaneouslyю

Comment: It's on both sides because I'm solving for $t$ such that $\int_\epsilon^1 \exp(-2tx) < \epsilon \int_0^1 \exp(-2tx)$. Two occurrences of $\epsilon$ represent numerical underflow occurring in two different places, at this point we can assume the integral is numerically 0.

Comment: Can you kindly elaborate how   these integrals  produce `E^(-ε t) Csch[t] Sinh[t - ε t]==ε`, giving us details?  I don't see any `Sinh` here.

Comment: @user64494 source of `sinh` expression is in the linked notebook, pasting here `Assuming[{1 > e > 0, t > 0}, 
 loss = FullSimplify[
   Integrate[Exp[-2 t h], {h, e, 1}]/
    Integrate[Exp[-2 t h], {h, 0, 1}]]]`

Comment: There is no linked notebook. Sorry, I have nothing to discuss with you in such a manner. You don't answer my request "Isn't it art for art's sake?". That's all.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Asymptotic analysis along the lines of @Roland's answer reveals that the root of
$$e^{-t \epsilon } \text{csch}(t) \sinh (t-t \epsilon ) = \epsilon$$
as $\epsilon\rightarrow 0$ is at
$t \sim \frac{1}{2\epsilon}\ln(1/\epsilon)$.

This code visually confirms it,

```
With[{ε=10^-p},
   Manipulate[
      Plot[E^(-ε t) Csch[t] Sinh[t-ε t]-ε,
      {t,-10,320},
      PlotRange->{-.5,2},
      Epilog->{Red,AbsolutePointSize[7],Point[{1/(2ε) Log[1/ε],0}]}],
   {p,1,5}]
]
```

and for $\epsilon = 10^{-9}$, we can easily evaluate this high quality approximation: $t = 1.036\times10^{10}$.

Comment: Substituting $\epsilon = 10^{-12}$ yields a root of $t=1.38\times 10^{13}$, consistent with @user64494's answer based on NMinimize.

Comment: -1. Sorry, "Asymptotic analysis along the lines of @Roland's answer reveals that the root of
e−tϵcsch(t)sinh(t−tϵ)=ϵ
as ϵ→0 is at t∼12ϵln(1/ϵ)" are empty words.

Comment: Indeed with `loss[ε_, t_] = E^(-ε t) Csch[t] Sinh[t - ε t]` we have $\varepsilon^{-1}\text{loss}\left(\varepsilon ,-\frac{\ln\varepsilon}{2\varepsilon}\right)=\frac{\varepsilon^{\frac{1}{\varepsilon}-1}-1}{\varepsilon^{\frac{1}{\varepsilon}}-1}$, which goes to 1 very rapidly as $\varepsilon\to0$. Try this: `Plot[{loss[ε, -Log[ε]/(2ε)]/ε, (ε^(1/ε-1)-1)/(ε^(1/ε)-1)}, {ε, 0, 0.2}]`.

Comment: @Ropman: Hope you understand that "which goes to 1 very rapidly as ε→0" are ungrounded words too.

Comment: @user64494 I understand very well that you understand nothing of these matters. Cheers!

Comment: @Roman: `\[CurlyEpsilon]^(-1)*
 loss[\[CurlyEpsilon], -Log[\[CurlyEpsilon]]/(2 \[CurlyEpsilon])]` results in `-((Csch[Log[\[CurlyEpsilon]]/(2 \[CurlyEpsilon])] Sinh[
   Log[\[CurlyEpsilon]]/2 - Log[\[CurlyEpsilon]]/(
    2 \[CurlyEpsilon])])/Sqrt[\[CurlyEpsilon]])`.

Comment: @Roman: And then `Limit[-((
  Csch[Log[\[CurlyEpsilon]]/(2 \[CurlyEpsilon])] Sinh[
    Log[\[CurlyEpsilon]]/2 - Log[\[CurlyEpsilon]]/(
     2 \[CurlyEpsilon])])/Sqrt[\[CurlyEpsilon]]), \[CurlyEpsilon] -> 
  0, Direction -> "FromAbove"]` produces `1`. However,, the derivation of  `-Log[\[CurlyEpsilon]]/(2 \[CurlyEpsilon])` is  explained by neither QuantumDot nor you.

Comment: @QuantumDot How did you get this very good approximation `t~1/(2ε) Log[1/ε]`, I didn't see it in RolandF's answer. Thanks!

Comment: Start with ansatz $t_\text{root} \sim c \epsilon^p$, with $p$ a real number, $c$ a possibly sub-polynomial function of $\epsilon$.  Then equation becomes $$\frac{\exp(2 c (1-\epsilon)\epsilon^p) - 1}{\exp(2 c \epsilon^p) - 1} \sim \epsilon\,.$$  Compare $\exp(\ldots)$ with $-1$ in numerator and denominator: if they were negligible, we would have $1\sim\epsilon$, a contradiction.  Therefore, the $\exp(\ldots)$ are dominant.  Dropping the $-1$'s, our equation becomes $\exp(-2 c \epsilon^{1+p})\sim\epsilon$.  To achieve balance we finally find $c = 1/2\ln(1/\epsilon)$ and $p=-1$.

Answer (score 2):

Approximate up to a certain order in $\varepsilon$

```
 f[t_] = ε /. Solve[Series[E^(-ε t) Csch[t] Sinh[t - ε t] == ε, {ε, 0, 3}] // Normal, ε]
```

and look for the real solution

```
 Plot[Evaluate[ReIm[f[t]]][[1]], {t, -4, 4}]
```

[image]

```
FindRoot[(E^(-ε t) Csch[t] Sinh[t - ε t] - ε ) /. {t -> 2}, {ε, 0.3}]
(* {ε->0.294713} *)
```

Comment: So the issue is precision when $t\approx 10^{12}$ or $\epsilon\approx 10^{-12}$. I tried series expansion around $t=\infty$ but it returns unevaluated

Comment: All that approximation is built on the sand.

Comment: We usually call it an approximation of 0 by very small values of 1.

Comment: In particular, `Limit[Series[
   E^(-\[CurlyEpsilon] t) Csch[t] Sinh[
      t - \[CurlyEpsilon] t] - \[CurlyEpsilon], {\[CurlyEpsilon], 0, 
    3}] // Normal, t -> Infinity, Assumptions -> \[CurlyEpsilon] > 0]` produces `-Infinity`, whereas `Limit[E^(-\[CurlyEpsilon] t) Csch[t] Sinh[
    t - \[CurlyEpsilon] t] - \[CurlyEpsilon], t -> Infinity, 
 Assumptions -> \[CurlyEpsilon] > 0]` results in `-\[CurlyEpsilon]`.

Answer (score -2):

Making use of `NMinimize` instead of `FindRoot`, one succeeds.

```
loss1 = E^(-\[CurlyEpsilon] t) Csch[t] Sinh[t - \[CurlyEpsilon] t] - \[CurlyEpsilon];
\[CurlyEpsilon] = 10^-12; NMinimize[{loss1^2, t >= 10^3}, t, WorkingPrecision -> 30]
```

> `{1.90868331977198098151173852671*10^-52, {t ->  1.38155105579642671963526697470*10^13}}`

```
NMinimize[{loss1^2, t >= 10^3}, t, WorkingPrecision -> 100]
```

> `{1.9086833197722663574515674286889244248591654406882070452413208387700\ 16934234187487647725103961189817*10^-122, {t ->  1.38155105579642741041079487281061852456066089317725687786471775836\ 5547144183076004688106490290838025*10^13}}`

Comment: What is wrong in my answer?

Comment: Probably nothing. The comments are another matter entirely. They are rude and mostly off-target. Again, this is not a mathematics forum, it is a forum for computing with a particular software product. Big difference.

Comment: I was reluctant to explain my –1 vote because you have a history of not accepting criticism. It's a terrible idea to convert a zero crossing into a minimum and then using a minimization algorithm to find it. Root-finding with [Newton's method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newton%27s_method) or other methods is much more efficient than minimum-finding: the error signal of a root finder is first-order, whereas the error signal of a minimizer is second-order. And if the minimum-finder differentiates the argument to convert it back to a root-finding problem, then it simply reverses the conversion